# PrestaShop 1.7.3 Product.php class override

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have PrestaShop 1.7.3.3 installed with php 7.1.18
When I override modules and place them in the override directory it works well.

for example I added `PrestaShop/override/modules/ps_languageselector/ps_languageselector.php` and the override is being executed.

when I try to override Product.php by placing a file at `PrestaShop/override/classes/Product.php`, the file is not being loaded at all! adding `die()` or `error_log` doesn't change anything.

what am I missing ?

thank you

Comment: What is your code of `.../Product.php`?

Comment: Remove file app/cache/dev/class_index.php it should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of PS1.7 is to extend instead of overriding.

But if you really must you still can override. 
Delete these 2 files:

> var/cache/dev/class_index.php & 
>   var/cache/prod/class_index.php

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find documents about the new extend method?

Comment: In PrestaShop 1.7.x versions, the `class_index.php` file to delete is now located in `prestashop\var\cache\prod`

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem,in my case problem was file permission ,in module/Moddule.php in addOverride function we have a line `file_put_contents($path_override, preg_replace('#(\r\n|\r)#ism', "\n", file_get_contents($path_override)))` that transfer your override to /override directory ,because of file permission this line doesn't execute ,so problem happen, run
`chmod -R 777 .` in your project directory solve the problem

Comment: I do advice not to set folder permissions to 777 on  a live environment. Please use 755 instead.